# what does __getstate_manages_dict__ do?

Tags: python, c++, oop, pickle, boost-python

I've been working on multiprocessing and C++ extensions and I don't quite get the `__getstate_manages_dict__` function (I know how to use it, but I'm not really sure how it works). The [boost/Python documentation for pickle support](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/python/doc/html/reference/topics/pickle_support.html) says this:

> The author of a Boost.Python extension class might provide a `__getstate__` method without considering the possibilities that: * his class is used in Python as a base class. Most likely the **dict** of instances of the derived class needs to be pickled in order to restore the instances correctly. * the user adds items to the instance's `__dict__` directly. Again, the `__dict__` of the instance then needs to be pickled.

> To alert the user to this highly unobvious problem, a safety guard is
> provided. If `__getstate__` is defined and the instance's `__dict__` is
> not empty, Boost.Python tests if the class has an attribute
> `__getstate_manages_dict__`. An exception is raised if this attribute is not defined:

I've seen some examples where the object's `__dict__` is returned in `__getstate__` and then updated in `__setstate__`. What is this `__dict__` refering to? Is it the `__dict__` attribute of the derived class object? Also, why does this dict needs to be handled explicitly if pickle calls `__init__` to create a new object and then sets the attribute?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know how to use it, but I'm not really sure how it works

It's a boolean value that is False by default. The point is to signal to Boost that the `__getstate__`/`__setstate__` implementation handles the class' `__dict__` attribute, so that the information won't be lost in the pickling process.

The idea is that Boost::Python can't actually determine whether the code is written properly, so instead you are made to jump through this extra hurdle so that, if you are unaware of the problem, you see an error message - as they say, `to alert the user to this highly unobvious problem`.

It's not doing anything magical. It's just there to confirm that you "read the warranty", so to speak.

> The boost/Python documentation for pickle support says this:

This is just explaining the reasons why it's important to consider the `__dict__` contents - even if you don't want to pickle all the attributes that you set explicitly in the `__init__` (for example, because the class holds a reference to a large resource that you intend to load in some other way, or a results cache, or...). In short, instances of your class might contain information that you didn't expect them to contain, and that your `__getstate__` implementation *won't know how to handle, unless it takes the instance's `__dict__` into account*.

Hence the "practical advice" offered: "If `__getstate__` is required, include the instance's `__dict__` in the Python object that is returned."

> What is this `__dict__` referring to? Is it the `__dict__` attribute of the derived class object?

It's the `__dict__` attribute of *the instance that `__getstate__` was called upon*. That could be an instance of a derived class, if that class doesn't override the methods. Or it could be an instance of the base class, which may or may not have had extra attributes added outside the class implementation.

> Also, why does this dict needs to be handled explicitly if pickle calls **init** to create a new object and then sets the attribute?

See above. When you *get* the attributes (so that the pickle file can be written), you need to make sure that you actually get all the necessary attributes, or else they'll be missing upon restoration. Hard-coded logic can miss some.

Comment: Ah I see. So the object has an attribute __dict__ that contains certain information, and some of those might go missing when pickling, and the easiest way to avoid that is to update the dict with getstate and setstate?

Comment: You aren't updating the `__dict__` with them; you're using the `__dict__` to get information for `__getstate__` to return. You *can* modify the `self` object's `__dict__` within `__setstate__` as a way of setting attributes, but it's easier to just set them in the normal way.